# Asp.Net Mvc JQuery autocomplete with multiple values?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

**CONTROLLER**

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetTags()
{
    var data = entity.Tags.Select(x => new { tagName = x.TagName });
    return Json(new { result = data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(function () {
    function split(val) {
        return val.split(/,\s*/);
    }
    function extractLast(term) {
        return split(term).pop();
    }
    $("#tags")
// don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
.bind("keydown", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
    $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active) {
    event.preventDefault();
        }
})
.autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetTags", "Question")', {
        term: extractLast(request.term)
}, response);
},
    search: function () {
        // custom minLength
    var term = extractLast(this.value);
    if (term.length < 2) {
        return false;
    }
    },
focus: function () {
    // prevent value inserted on focus
    return false;
    },
select: function (event, ui) {
    var terms = split(this.value);
    // remove the current input
    terms.pop();
    // add the selected item
    terms.push(ui.item.value);
    // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
    terms.push("");
    this.value = terms.join(", ");
    return false;
    }
});
});
```

In fact, Script are from default [jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-multi-values](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-source)

**RAZOR**

```
<div class="demo">
    <div class="ui-widget">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Title, new { @class = "my_text_box", id = "tags" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller Action is triggered, But I can't see any data in textbox. I debugged javascript, but function does not trigger. How can I fix it?

I can do `auto-complete-with-multi-values` with another way, not this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Action method is returning a collection of Objects, that would be structured like this;

```
[ { tagName: result1}, {tagName: result2} ... ]
```

Because you use the result directly for the autocomplete, the method needs to return data in one of the [following two formats](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp);

> The data from local data, a url or a callback can come in two
>   variants:
>
> An Array of Strings:
>       `[ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]`
>
> An Array of Objects with
>   label and value properties:
>   `[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]`

Alternatively, you could take the results and map them appropriately to one of the above formats before posting them to the response method.

Comment: when I wrote :`(x => new { label = x.TagName, value = x.TagId })` It still does not work.

Comment: sorry it works. But the problem is its position. my textbox is downstream of the page. But auto complete datas are shown above the page. Any idea aout this?